# Parallel on unix with screen

Tags: shell, unix, gnu-screen

Is there a way to run in parallel? I can manually start screens, but I need to start up 30.
I attempted to do it by hand (stupid yeah) but I got confused halfway through and decided I better ask stackoverflow.

```
#!/bin/bash --login
  2
  3
  4
  5
  6   avida=~/avida/cbuild/bin/avida
  7   skeleton_dir=~/cse845/no_pred
  8 # wd=/mnt/scratch/cse845_avida/predator_sim
  9   wd=~/cse845/no_predator_editor_sim_wd
 10
 11 for i in {1..30}
 12 do
 13 screen
 14
 15 
 16   sim_num=${i}
 17   sim_dir=${wd}/sim_$sim_num
 18   mkdir $sim_dir
 19   cd $sim_dir
 20   cp ${skeleton_dir}/*.cfg ${skeleton_dir}/*.org ./
 21   $avida &> avida_log.txt
 22# Here I would like to do the equivalent of exiting screen manually, ^A, d
 23 done
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to start 3 at the same time in a shell script (the -d -m starts them in the background)

```
screen -s "name1" -c ~/screen/name1.screenrc -d -m 
screen -s "name2" -c ~/screen/name2.screenrc -d -m 
screen -s "name3" -c ~/screen/name3.screenrc -d -m
```

Then you could have a variable number of tabs/windows within each screen, specified in your screenrc files.  (with -t).

See example screenrc file designed to work well with emacs: https://github.com/startup-class/dotfiles/blob/master/.screenrc

This is the only Section about specifying which tabs/windows per socket.

```
# 2.3) Autoload two screen tabs for emacs/bash.
screen -t emacs 0
screen -t bash 1
```

So when you do **screen -ls** you would get

```
There are screens on:
    4149.name1  (07/10/13 22:18:44) (Detached)
    4018.name2  (07/10/13 22:18:23) (Detached)
    3882.name3  (07/10/13 22:17:08) (Detached)
3 Sockets in /var/run/screen/S-yourid.
```

And then if you wanted to connect to name1, you'd do **screen -r 4149** or **screen -r name1**

Answer (score 0):

I see two things right away:

1. You are missing the necessary backslashes to escape your newlines in the screen command arguments.
2. You need to tell screen to run in the background.  See the `-d` and `-m` options.

Comment: 1. Backslashes to escape my newlines? Could you elaborate please? I don't understand. 2. ah so -d -m creates a screen but doesn't attach to it - src http://www.slac.stanford.edu/comp/unix/package/epics/extensions/iocConsole/screen.1.html

Comment: I mean when you have code like `screen <newline> cmd...`, bash is going to interpret that as a call to screen with no arguments following by a call to cmd.  You want it to all be one thing, so it has to be either on one line, or like `screen \<newline> cmd...`.